# Reading Avro message from topic using KafkaStream converting them into string/json and storing in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a usecase where i have to read message from kafka topic as stream in Avro format and convert it into string and then store it into AWS S3 bucket.

```
@Configuration
public class MessagePromotion {
@Autowired
private AmazonS3 s3client;
 
@Value("${aws.s3.bucket}")
private String awsS3Bucket;

@Autowired

@Bean
public KStream<String, testEvent> kstreamPromotionUppercase(StreamsBuilder builder) {
    
    
    KStream<String, testEvent> sourceStream = builder.stream("test-topic");
    
    

    //sourceStream.print(Printed.<String, testEvent>toSysOut().withLabel("Original Stream"));
    
    sourceStream.mapValues(testEvent -> new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(testEvent));
    

    


    s3client.putObject(awsS3Bucket, "test3", sourceStream.toString() );
    

    return sourceStream;
}}
```

I was able to read message in Avro but not able to convert it into string/json. I am doing something wrong here

```
 sourceStream.mapValues(testEvent -> new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(testEvent));
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `sourceStream.mapValues()` is a `KStream` that is a logical abstraction of a data stream -- it's not a real "container" like a Java `Map` or `List` etc and thus, calling `KStream.toString()` is similar to calling `Object.toString()`... It does not really do anything.

If you want to iterator over all messages, you would call `foreach()`

```
KStream<String, String> converted = sourceStream.mapValues(...);
converted.foreach((k, v) -> s3client.putObject(awsS3Bucket, "test3", v));
```

However also note, that `StreamsBuilder` only declares a dataflow (ie, it build up a plan but does not execute anything). To actually kick of the computation you need to create `KafakStreams` client, pass in the `Topology` from `StreamBuilder#build()` and `start()` the client.

I would highly recommend that you check out the docs, read the intro and to the quickstart to understand better how Kafka Streams works: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/